# How to use vectors from Doc2Vec in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, word2vec, doc2vec

I am trying to use `Doc2Vec` to convert sentences to vectors, then use those vectors to train a tensorflow classifier.

I am a little confused at what tags are used for, and how to extract all of the document vectors from `Doc2Vec` after it has finished training.

My code so far is as follows:

```
fake_data = pd.read_csv('./sentences/fake.txt', sep='\n')
real_data = pd.read_csv('./sentences/real.txt', sep='\n')
sentences = []

for i, row in fake_data.iterrows():
    sentences.append(TaggedDocument(row['title'].lower().split(), ['fake', len(sentences)]))

for i, row in real_data.iterrows():
    sentences.append(TaggedDocument(row['title'].lower().split(), ['real', len(sentences)]))

model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec(sentences)
```

I get vectors when I do `print(model.docvecs[1])` etc, but they are different every time I remake the model.

First of all: have I used `Doc2Vec` correctly?
Second: Is there a way I can grab all documents tagged 'real' or 'fake', then turn them into a numpy array and pass it into tensorflow?

Comment: Doc2vec in gensim package is not tensorflow, it is independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `tag` that you use for each `TaggedDocument` is not what you expect. Doc2Vec algorithm is learning vector representations of the specified *tags* (some of which can be shared between the documents). So if your goal is simply to convert sentences to vectors, the recommended choice of a tag is some kind of unique sentence identifier, such as sentence index.

The learned model is then stored in `model.docvecs`. E.g., if you use sentence index as a tag, you can then get the 1st document vector by accessing `model.docvecs` for the tag `"0"`, the second document - for the tag `"1"`, and so on.

Example code:

```py
documents = [doc2vec.TaggedDocument(sentence, ['real-%d' % i])
             for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences)]
model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec(documents, vector_size=10)  # 10 is just for illustration

# Raw vectors are stored in `model.docvecs.vectors_docs`.
# It's easier to access each one by the tag, which are stored in `model.docvecs.doctags`.
for tag in model.docvecs.doctags.keys():
  print(tag, model.docvecs[tag])  # Prints the learned numpy array for this tag
```

By the way, to control the model randomness, use `seed` parameter of `Doc2Vec` class.